# A very interesting integral: $\int\limits^{2}_{1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x!-\sqrt{(x!)!-\sqrt{((x!)!)!-\dots}}}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, factorial, nested-radicals

I really like infinitely nested radicals so when I was messing around with them in Desmos, I noticed that the domain of $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x!-\sqrt{(x!)!-\sqrt{((x!)!)!-\dots}}}}$ seemed to converge to $1<x<2$. Interested, I tried using averages of the integrals of partial parts of the equation (starting with $\sqrt{x}$, $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x!}}$, and so on) to estimate the convergence of the infinitely repeating equation (assuming it actually converges) and got [0.871327768063](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n7twm1rmeh). I only went to ten repetitions because I was doing it manually so I doubt the accuracy of this value.

However, I would really to have an exact form (though I doubt one exists) and I have no idea how to solve the integral and have been unable to find any relevant MSE questions I can look at. My only idea is that I would have to change the factorials into gamma functions. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you proved convergence?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that? I think it appears to converge but that is obviously not enough.

Comment: Note that $\Gamma(x+1)\leq x$ on the interval $[1,2],$ so the function is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1+4x}).$

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how someone could solve this integral without being able to solve the functional equation $f(x)^2+f(\Gamma(x+1))=x,$ but I don't know any special integral tricks, so someone might have a clever solution.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say finding a closed form is a completely hopeless endeavor.  Determining the convergence of the integral seems like a more interesting problem.

Comment: @MandelBroccoli How dd you get this functional equation?

Comment: If you let the integrand be $f(x)$ then it satisfies $x-f(x!)= f(x)^2,$ which is the same thing as what I wrote earlier.

Comment: @C-RAM https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829228/does-this-ridiculous-integral-converge

My now slightly less naive self agrees with you about this integral being a hopeless endeavor.