# Does this ridiculous integral converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, factorial, nested-radicals

I was looking through some of my older questions, when I came across [this crazy integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713356/a-very-interesting-integral-int-limits2-1-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-s) I posted.

$\int\limits^{2}_{1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x!-\sqrt{(x!)!-\sqrt{((x!)!)!-\dots}}}}dx$

I had approximated it at $0.871327768063$. Reading the comments, I noticed C-Ram said determining the convergence of the integral seems like a more interesting problem and I agree.

This is still way over my skill level and I don't know how to even attempt proving convergence but I am still curious about how it could be done.

Comment: @Jam This is why I thought it might converge: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n7twm1rmeh